# Holomorphic function on $D(0,1)$ such that $f(D(0,1)) = \overline{D(0,1)}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Does there exist such function?

I know that there is no homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$, because you can remove two points from $[0,1]$ and still have connected space and you can't do that in $(0,1)$.

Here however, we're looking at holomorphic functions and not homeomorphisms. Can I use the above result to conclude there is no such function?

Comment: I am not sure you can. I think you are supposed to use the fact that holomorphic fonctions are open maps in some way depending on what is consired as known or not.

Comment: Oh, right - this is the theorem I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A holomorphic function is open (the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis))) so $f[D(0,1)]$ is open (assuming $D(0,1)$ is the open disk) and so cannot be equal to the closed set $\overline{D(0,1)}$, by connectedness of $\Bbb C$, which tells us that the only subsets that are both open and closed are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Hi professor Brandsma, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668359/if-fa-rightarrow-bbbrn-is-a-bijection-such-that-f-in-cr-and-detdx)?