# If $f:A\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^n$ is a bijection such that $f\in C^r$ and $\det[Df(x)]\neq 0$ then $f[A]$ is open and $f^{-1}\in C^r$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, inverse-function

What shown below is a reference from "Analysis on manifolds" by James R. Munkres.
[image]
So I don't understand why the function $\phi$ defined in the step $2$ is of class $C^r$: clearly $f(x)-c$ is of class $C^r$ but I don't know if the norm $||\cdot||$ and the square are of class $C^r$. Then I don't understand the final step $5$: indeed I don't understand why $I\in C^\infty$ and $Df\in C^{(r-1)}$. Indeed as reference I point out that Munkres said that if $f$ is a function mapping an open set $A$ of $\Bbb{R}^m$ into $\Bbb{R}^n$ then we say that $f$ is of class $C^r$ if and only if the partial derivatives of the functions $f_i$ of order less than or equal to $r$ are continuous on $A$, but unfortunately the function $Df:A\rightarrow GL(n)$ and $I:GL(n)\rightarrow GL(n)$ are not vector fields so I don't understand what Munkres says in step $5$. So to prove the statement I am only sure that I have to prove that the entries of $Dg$ are of class $C^{r-1}$. However perhaps I can explain the step $5$ as below.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The square of the norm is just a sum of squares which is in itself even $C^\infty$ so composing it with a $C^r$ function preserves that class.

Comment: That $I$ is $C^\infty$ follows from the determinants/subdeterminants formula for the inverse of a matrix, which follows from Cramer’s rule.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Okay, but it seems to me that to claim that $Df, I\in C^{r-1}$ is not consistent with the reference that I gave: Munkres defines the writing $z\in C^r$ iff $z$ is a vector field, but unfortunately $Df$ and $I$ are not vector fiels.

Comment: he isn’t talking about vector fields but doing an induction proof. That’s why he has the assumption involving $r-1$.

Comment: Okay, but if he defined the writing $z\in C^r$ only for vector field then if $Df$ and $I$ are not vector field how can he assume that $Df, I\in C^{r-1}$? It seems strange to me.

Comment: $C^r$ class is a class of functions.

Comment: Perhaps thanks to your words I have found another way to explain what Munkres wants say.

Comment: Well first of all we know that the sum and and product of $C^r$ functions is a $C^r$ function so using permutation we know that for any square matrix $A$ it is $detA:=\sum_{\sigma\mathfrak{S}}sgn(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdot...\cdot a_{n,\sigma(n)}$ and so if the elements of a square matrix $A$ are functions of class $C^r$ then the determinant is even $C^r$. Now by Cramer formula we know that if $B:=A^{-1}$, where $A$ is a square matrix, then $b_{i,j}=\frac{(-1)^{i+j}|A_{i,j}|}{|A|}$ and so if the elements of $A$ are functions of class $C^{r}$ then even the elements of $B$ are of class $C^r$.

Comment: So then we remember that the composition of $C^r$ functions is even $C^r$.

Comment: Now we know that $f, g\in C^0$ and so $f\circ g\in C^0$ and so for what we observe the elements of $Dg(y)\equiv[Df(g(y))]^{-1}$ are continuous.

Comment: So we assume that the theorem holds for functions of class $C^{r-1}$. Let $f$ be of class $C^r$. Then in particular $f$ is of class $C^{r-1}$ so that (by the induction of hypothesis) the inverse function $g$ is of class $C^{r-1}$ and so even $f\circ g$ is of clas $C^{r-1}$. Furthermore the elements of $Df$ are functions of class $C^{r-1}$. Finally if $Dg(y)\equiv[Df(g(y))]^{-1}$ then for what we previously observed we conclude that the elements of $Dg$ are of class $C^{r-1}$ and so $g$ is of class $C^r$. Is it right what I have said?

Comment: Yes, that's about right. Write it up as an answer?

Comment: Umm...one time I answered at my question but it seemed rather strange. Anyway berfore to do this I want only to point out one last thing. Above we have said that the sum and product of $C^r$ functions is even $C^r$ and so know we observe that for the universal mapping theorem for products it follows that a vector field $f:A$ that mapping a subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}^m$ into $\Bbb{R}^m$ is $C^r$ if and only if $f_i$ is $C^r$ for any $i:1,...,n$.

Comment: So we observe that if $f(x)$ is $C^r$ then clearly $f_i(x)-c_i$ is even $C^r$ and so that we immediately conclude that $||f(x)-c||^2\equiv\sum_{i=1}^n(f_i(x)-c_i)^2$ is $C^r$, right?

Comment: Yes, almost immediately, we're using composition arguments again, of course.

Comment: Okay. Therefore tomorrow morning I will surely write this as an answer: now it's late here. Anyway thanks so much!!! Good night.

Comment: Ho sap. Bona nit! Vaig a dormir ara..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi professor, as you can see below I answered at the question. However while I did it I have had a doubt. As you can see in the step $4$ Munkres use a previous lemma which presume that $f\in C^1$ and so I argue that the Munkres's proof is correct iff $r>0$ and after all this seems consistent with what Munkres observe below the figure $8.2$. Anyway Munkres said beforehand that $f\in C^r$ if and only if the partial derivatives of the funcions $f_i$ of order less than or equal to $r$ are continuous and so by this definition clearly $r>0$. So what can you say about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we know that the sum and and product of $C^r$ functions is a $C^r$ function so by permutation formula for determinant we know that for any square matrix $A$ it is 
$$
detA:=\sum_{\sigma\mathfrak{S}}sgn(\sigma)a_{1,\sigma(1)}\cdot...\cdot a_{n,\sigma(n)}
$$
and so if the elements of a square matrix are functions of class $C^r$ then the determinant is even a $C^r$ function; moreover by Cramer formula we know that if $B:=A^{-1}$ then 
$$
b_{i,j}=\frac{(-1)^{i+j}|A_{i,j}|}{|A|}
$$ 
and so if the elements of $A$ are $C^{r}$ functions then even the elements of $B$ are $C^r$ functions.

Finally we remember that the composition of $C^r$ functions is even $C^r$.

So we know that $f, g\in C^0$ and so $f\circ g\in C^0$ and so for what we observe the elements of $Dg(y)\equiv[Df(g(y))]^{-1}$ are continuous. So we assume that the theorem holds for functions of class $C^{r-1}$. Let $f$ be of class $C^r$ so that in particular $f$ is of class $C^{r-1}$ and thus (by the induction of hypothesis) the inverse function $g$ is of class $C^{r-1}$ and so even $f\circ g$ is of clas $C^r$; moreover the elements of $Df$ are functions of class $C^{r-1}$. Finally if $Dg(y)\equiv[Df(g(y))]^{-1}$ then for what we previously observed we conclude that the elements of $Dg$ are of class $C^{r-1}$ and so $g$ is of class $C^r$.

Well we remember that above we have said that the sum and product of $C^r$ functions is even $C^r$; moreover we can immediately observe that for the universal mapping theorem for products it follows that a vector field $f$ that mapping a subset $A$ of $\Bbb{R}^m$ into $\Bbb{R}^n$ is $C^r$ if and only if $f_i$ is $C^r$ for any $i:1,...,n$.

So we finally observe that if $f(x)$ is $C^r$ then clearly $\big(f_i(x)−c_i\big)$ is even $C^r$ so that we immediately conclude that $||f(x)−c||^2≡∑_{i=1}^n(f_i(x)−c_i)^2$ is $C^r$.